# Transformar um Array Json em outro JSON usando node

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema na montagem de um JSON usando NodeJS. 
Tenho um retorno de um SQL gigante que segue basicamente a estrutura abaixo.

```
[
  {
    "numDoc":"0000001",
    "OutrosCampos":"outrosDados",
    "itens":[
      {
        "itemNum":"000000001",
        "nome":"AAAAAAAAA",
        "agrup":"00003",
        "numDoc":"0000001"
      },
      {
        "itemNum":"000000002",
        "nome":"BBBBBBB",
        "agrup":"00003",
        "numDoc":"0000001"
      },
      {
        "itemNum":"000000003",
        "nome":"CCCCCCCCCC",
        "agrup":"00003",
        "numDoc":"0000001"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

e preciso que meu JSON siga a seguinte estrutura de saída:

```
[
  {
    "numDoc":"0000001",
    "OutrosCampos":"outrosDados",
    "itens":[
      {
        "agrup":"00003",
        "itensAgrup":[
          {
            "itemNum":"000000001",
            "nome":"AAAAAAAAA"
          },
          {
            "itemNum":"000000002",
            "nome":"BBBBBBB"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "agrup":"00004",
        "itensAgrup":[
          {
            "itemNum":"000000003",
            "nome":"CCCCCCCCCC"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Resumindo, preciso que o primeiro array (que tem o `numDoc`) continue intacto, que o segundo array (o itens) seja separado por um array pelo agrupamento, em que não aparecesse mais o campo repetido numDOC e nem o agrupamento se fosse possível.

Estou usando nodeJS e também diversas "packages" como o underscore mas não estou conseguindo transformar o array neste JSON.

OBS: Preciso ler chave e valor, pois esta estrutura, pode variar os nomes dos campos e a quantidade de itens, por isso não posso tentar colocar em um "array" fixo.

Qualquer dúvida, podem falar.
Grato pela ajuda desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando javascript puro, ficou da seguinte forma:

```js
var retorno = [{
  "numDoc": "0000001",
  "OutrosCampos": "outrosDados",
  "itens": [{
    "itemNum": "000000001",
    "nome": "AAAAAAAAA",
    "agrup": "00003",
    "numDoc": "0000001"
  }, {
    "itemNum": "000000002",
    "nome": "BBBBBBB",
    "agrup": "00003",
    "numDoc": "0000001"
  }, {
    "itemNum": "000000003",
    "nome": "CCCCCCCCCC",
    "agrup": "00003",
    "numDoc": "0000001"
  }, {
    "itemNum": "000000004",
    "nome": "CCCCCCCCCC",
    "agrup": "00004",
    "numDoc": "0000001"
  }]
}];

// Variável com o valor final da conversão
var novoRetorno = [];

retorno.map(function(item) {

  // Objeto temporário, será inserido no final
  var tmp = {
    numDoc: item.numDoc,
    OutrosCampos: item.OutrosCampos,
    itens: [],
  };

  // Objeto temporário, será utilizado para armazenar os itens agrupados
  var tmp2 = {};
  item.itens.map(function(item2) {
    // Cria o agrupamento caso não exista, se existir utiliza ele
    tmp2[item2.agrup] = tmp2[item2.agrup] || {};
    // Define o nome do agrup
    tmp2[item2.agrup].agrup = item2.agrup;
    // Resgata os itens já criados ou cria um array vazio
    tmp2[item2.agrup].itensAgrup = tmp2[item2.agrup].itensAgrup || [];
    // Inseri no array de itens o novo item
    tmp2[item2.agrup].itensAgrup.push({
      itemNum: item2.itemNum,
      nome: item2.nome,
    });
  });

  // Loop para remover a key e inserir o objeto puro
  for (var key in tmp2) {
    if (tmp2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      tmp.itens.push(tmp2[key]);
    }
  }

  // Insere o objeto final no retorno
  novoRetorno.push(tmp);

});

// Magic!
console.log(novoRetorno);
```

Answer (score 1):

Comece criando um mapeamento e depois transforme para o formato desejado.

```js
var objeto = [
  {
    "numDoc":"0000001",
    "OutrosCampos":"outrosDados",
    "itens":[
      {
        "itemNum":"000000001",
        "nome":"AAAAAAAAA",
        "agrup":"00003",
        "numDoc":"0000001"
      },
      {
        "itemNum":"000000002",
        "nome":"BBBBBBB",
        "agrup":"00003",
        "numDoc":"0000001"
      },
      {
        "itemNum":"000000003",
        "nome":"CCCCCCCCCC",
        "agrup":"00004",
        "numDoc":"0000001"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var agrupar = objeto[0].itens.reduce(function(obj, item){
    obj[item.agrup] = obj[item.agrup] || [];
    var valores = { "itemNum": item.itemNum, "nome": item.nome };
    obj[item.agrup].push(valores);
    return obj;
}, {});

var grupos = Object.keys(agrupar).map(function(key){
    return {agrup: key, itensAgrup: agrupar[key]};
});

objeto[0].itens = grupos;
console.log(objeto);
```

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) e [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), permitem que você obtenha construções poderosas de alto nível que podem poupar tempo e código comparado à iteração manual.

Comment: opa, usando a sua resposta, se eu quisesse inserir uma outra informação, antes de agrupamento de itens, tipo, 
{...
  {agrup : 000003,
   nomeAgrup : ZZZZZZZ,
   itens: [...
adicionar somente essa linha nome agrup, que está, no array original, junto com o código dos itens, como seria ?

Answer (score 0):

Eu nunca usei `underscore`, mas de acordo com a documentação funcionaria se você aplicasse assim, considerando `resp` como o retorno do `SQL`:

```
_.groupBy(resp[0].itens, function(item) { return item.agrup; });
```